# Add batch filter as variable

Tags: filter, batch

I want to add a batch filter with a variable number depending on a conditional. Is this even possible this way:

```
{% if category.id == '647' %}
    {% set nr = '5' %}
{% else %}
    {% set nr = '4' %}
{% endif %}


{% for batch in craft.entries.section('xy')|batch('{{ nr }}') %}
    {{ batch.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

This doesn't work. How should I write `{{ nr }}` or is it impossible due to things like parse order?

Comment: Have you tried it as just `batch(nr)` ? without brackets and single quotes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thought I would add this as an answer instead as it should solve your issue.

I think the issue with writing it like `batch('{{ nr }}')` is that twig sees whatever is in `''` as a string, so is seeing `{{ nr }}` as it is.

You also don't need to echo a variable as a function parameter i.e `batch({{ nr }})`, you just need to reference the variable itself.

So by just writing

```
{% for batch in craft.entries.section('xy')|batch(nr) %}
 {{ batch.title }}
{% endfor %
```

Twig will take the value for `nr` set above and use it as the parameter :)

Comment: Of course I didn't try the easiest possibility ;) thank you.